# Perform lm() for each row of a data.frame, where predictor lengths are different

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, apply, lm

I am trying to create a loop that perform lm on each row of a dataframe (response) against a predictor vector which is outside data frame. Values and length of the predictor varies depending on which category (df$Group) the row belongs to.
Appreciate if you could help me to create a loop that performs lm for each row, which also saves coefficients to a single vector/ dataframe. Also, to run the loop through several dataframes with same structure and then save coefficients to a single dataframe what changes should I make to the code?
Below is what I tried- it does not save coefficients.

```
dfList <- list(df,df1,df2)

df <- data.frame(ID=c(1:10),Group=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B"), T1= rnorm(10, mean=1, sd=1),
T2= rnorm(10, mean=2, sd=1),T3= seq(40,58,by=2),T4= seq(10,28,by=2))

A <- df$ID
B <- df$Group
C <- numeric(length=length(A))
x1 <- c(1:4)
x2 <- c(2:4)

for (i in length(A)){
  if(B[i] == "A"){C[i] <- apply(df[,c(3:6)],1,function(y) lm(y~x1)$coefficients[2])[i]}
  if(B[i] == "B"){C[i] <- apply(df[,c(4:6)],1,function(y)lm(y~x2)$coefficients[2])[i]}
}
```

Appreciate any help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this ?

```
list_df <- split(df, df$Group)
A_coeff <- apply(list_df[[1]][, 3:6], 1, function(y) lm(y~x1)$coefficients[2])
B_coeff <- apply(list_df[[2]][, 4:6], 1, function(y) lm(y~x2)$coefficients[2])
```